# Who changed my Chinese character?

Tags: fonts, xetex, xecjk

Let's run this snippet with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Source Han Serif SC}  % SimSun is OK
\begin{document}
见
\end{document}
```

The document body is a single Chinese character, 见 (U+89C1). Using the font Source Han Serif SC, the generated PDF contains another character ⻅ (U+2EC5). Using SimSun, the generated PDF contains the original 见 (U+89C1).

Could anyone tell me who is to blame: fontspec, xeCJK, or Source Han Serif SC; and how to stick to the original character in all cases? Thanks.

Comment: if you add `\showoutput` which character does it show in the log?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The log shows 见 (U+89C1).

Comment: so I think that means xetex and harfbuzz think that is the character added, so I think it points to something in the font (I don't have the font to test) If you remove xecjk and just use `\setmainfont` you should be able to compare with lualatex, what happens there...

Comment: can you check with fontforge or similar if the Han Serif SC font has a 89C1 glyph?

Comment: Wow, didn't think of that! It turns out Source Han Serif SC doesn't have this glyph. It feels quite weird because 见 is a very common Chinese character, and Source Han Serif SC a quite comprehensive font. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Sorry I used a simplistic font viewer to make the conclusion too soon. SourceHanSansSC-Regular.otf does contain 见 (U+89C1) but in an unusual way. The glyph is cid37659 which has 2 codepoints, U+2EC5 and U+89C1. XeLaTeX chooses the lower value by default, I suppose? Adding \XeTeXgenerateactualtext=1 fixes the issue. It's exactly the same issue as https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/286 and http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2017-June/027142.html. Thanks again for your guidance.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer and self-accept it, thanks. Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that SourceHanSansSC-Regular.otf does contain 见 (U+89C1) but in an unusual way. The glyph is cid37659 which has 2 codepoints, U+2EC5 and U+89C1. XeLaTeX somehow chooses the lower value. Adding `\XeTeXgenerateactualtext=1` fixes the issue for PDF viewers that support the "[actual text](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/What-difference-title-actual-text-alternative-text-figure-properties-image-q16218.aspx)" feature (Adobe Reader does; SumatraPDF doesn't).

The same issue was reported in https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/286 (partly in Chinese) and http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2017-June/027142.html. It seems that a [patch](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2017-June/027148.html) has been submitted but not yet universally adopted (my environment: MiKTeX 2.9 with the latest update on Windows 10).

Many thanks to David Carlisle for the gentle guidance.