# How to get correct content from PDF copying/pasting with Source Han?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, opentype

I installed the “Language-specific OTFs” version of Source Han Sans from [Adobe Font’s Release page](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/tree/release/OTF/SimplifiedChinese), e.g., `SourceHanSansSC-Regular.otf`, which sets the default ideographs suitable under Simplified Chinese convention but still provides “full character coverage or the ability to language-tag text to use glyphs that are appropriate for the other languages”.

When I create a PDF via

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SourceHanSansSC-Regular.otf}
\newcommand\test{\char"8FD4 E567F\par}
\begin{document}
\test
\addfontfeatures{Script=CJK Ideographic,Language=Chinese Simplified}
\test
\addfontfeatures{Script=CJK Ideographic,Language=Chinese Traditional}
\test
\addfontfeatures{Script=CJK Ideographic,Language=Chinese Hong Kong}
\test
\addfontfeatures{Script=CJK Ideographic,Language=Japanese}
\test
\addfontfeatures{Script=CJK Ideographic,Language=Korean}
\test
\end{document}
```

The output *looks* fine, with the ideograph `U+8FD4` in its five different forms. Also, notice that the digit height is slightly lower than the cap height in Latin/Default Script while the two are equal in CJK Script. This is desirable design in different scripts.

[image: Source Han Sans test]

But copying/pasting from the PDF has problem:

```
From XeLaTeX    From LuaLaTeX
返EF        返E５６７F
返E567F          返E567F
E567F          返E567F
E567F          返E567F
E567F          返E567F
E567F          返E567F
```

Observe that both engines have problem with digits under Latin Script: XeTeX thinks they are “tofu” while LuaTeX thinks they are “fullwidth”-variants (`U+FF10`–`U+FF19`). Furthermore, XeTeX fails to embed the ideograph info `U+8FD4` for languages other than Simplified Chinese into the PDF.

- My OS: Windows 8 and the fonts are installed system-wise.
- My TeX Distribution: MiKTeX 2.9.7000 with everything up to date (as of 2019/04/30).
- My PDF Viewer: Adobe Acrobat Reader where I did the copying/pasting.

Maybe related posts:

- [[XeTeX] CID-keyed font support?](https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2014-July/025385.html) from 2014.
- [Korean characters scrambled [XeLaTeX; Noto Sans Korean]?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191931/korean-characters-scrambled-xelatex-noto-sans-korean), also from 2014.

---

**Added**: It appears that issuing `\XeTeXgenerateactualtext=1` in the preamble fixes the copying/pasting problem for XeTeX, see also [Who changed my Chinese character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455010). Any ideas about LuaTeX?

I also found many CMap files in the [Resources folder of the Release branch](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/tree/release/Resources). Should I use `UniSourceHanSansCN-UTF16-H` and, if so, how?

Comment: On "normal" pdflatex the package `cmap` helped me a lot. I don't now if it works with xetex or luatex.

Comment: Regarding the digits I would suggest that you add an issue at the font github.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Negative. The digit substitution is documented on page 18 of the [official font readme file](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/raw/release/SourceHanSansReadMe.pdf) (in English). The equal digit height and cap height version is encoded by default, while the lower digit height version is commonly used in Latin fonts (such as CM, Minion, etc.). Copying/pasting from the readme file (probably generated by Adobe’s commercial software) shows no problem, so it is unlikely a font problem.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I just realized that `\XeTeXgenerateactualtext=1` helps in the XeTeX case. Unfortunately, this new primitive (added in 2016) has not been documented AFAIK. See the thread [potential new feature: `\XeTeXgenerateactualtext`](https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2016-February/026451.html) and the still opened ticket [#124 Document `\XeTeXgenerateactualtext`](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/124/).